# How to remove subwoofer carpet?

Tags: body-work

I am allergic to fabric so want to move the carpet on my subwoofer.  It seems to be glued down.  Preferably without using chemicals, is there a quick and easy way to remove it?  Also what is the proper way to remove it, with chemicals if needed?

Thanks

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That should be posted in the answer box.

Comment: Most likely there is no "proper way" to remove it, because its main function is to stop objects getting inside the box and damaging the speaker cone.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this a dust mite allergy? There may be a way to treat the carpet to remove/prevent allergens.

Comment: The best way to remove something that is glued, is not "quick and easy" but "slow and careful". If you peel away something that is glued, you must give the glue a chance to separate. Otherwise your tear the thing you are removing (or even damage what's underneath, such a paint layer), and end up peeling off a large number or torn shreds, taking even longer. Going slowly, you get the chance to remove it whole, and most of the glue too.

Comment: You might see if a heat gun on medium will soften the glue so it can be peeled.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove all the working parts of the subwoofer.

Most commercial boxes are only glued at the edges - it's cheaper if you use less glue. Try a hot air gun on a seam, with a thin taping knife to get underneath. If it starts coming away, continue. If it makes no difference, then you're going to either be cutting it off with a knife, or breaking the box down so you can use it to make templates for a new box that you build yourself.

You can also go on Amazon and find a pre-built, unfinished enclosure that will fit your car and the drivers that you've removed from this one

Answer (score 0):

If you can peel up one corner then get yourself a paint scraper like this one:

[image: Husky 15-in-1 Painter's Tool]

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-15-in-1-Painter-s-Tool-18PT0846/309098036

and work your way between the box and carpet.

If you cannot peel up a corner then get a utility knife, pick a section to score, and then jam the paint scraper in there.

If this doesn't work then you can look into building your own enclosure from plywood.